# Why published Array does not change after I change him in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

So, this is just a sample code from my project. After I call SecondView, I want to change names in the array to "LoL", and display them. Why init() does not change my array? Since it does not display new names

```
struct Person: Identifiable {
let id = UUID()
var name: String
var index: Int

}

class User: ObservableObject {
@Published var array = [Person(name: "Nick", index: 0),
                        Person(name: "John", index: 1)
]
}

struct ContentView: View {

@ObservedObject var user = User()

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        ForEach (user.array) { row in
            SecondView(name: row.name, index: row.index)
        }
    }
}
}

struct SecondView: View {

@ObservedObject var user = User()
var name = ""
var index = 0

init() {
    user.array[index].name = "LoL"
}

init(name: String, index: Int) {
    self.name = name
    self.index = index
}

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text(name)
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are not calling `init()` method in `SecondView` but you are calling `init(name:, index:)`. Notice how you use `SecondView` initializer inside your `FirstView`'s iteration (ie. `ForEach`) loop.

Also your second view displays the name that is passed along the initializer `init(name:index:)`, not the one from your `user` array. So, if you want to change `name` to something, do that before this `init(name:index:)` is called, and pass the name from user array.

You can do it inside your first view.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject var user = User()

    init() {
        user.array[0].name = "LoL"

    }
    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            ForEach (user.array) { row in
                SecondView(name: row.name, index: row.index)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that it will now change the first name to `Lol` because we change it inside `ContentView`'s initializer which then uses the same modified name.

Comment: What if I just want to change array and it will change it everywhere. Is there an alternative for init()?